# Cannot read top of Undefined jquery scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've tried to find a solution to this error but with no luck so I'll post my specific problem. I have a jquery scroll that scrolls to the hashtags in the menu and when reached the specific target hashtags it should change the menu item color from grey to white. Everything works fine with one small error.

When you click on the menu item it scrolls down but then you have to scroll 1-5px more in order for the script to change the menu item to active (white color), the console also gives me a "cannot read property 'top' of undefined. Im clueless because the script gathers the menu items in an array and if I console.log the array the items are there. If I console.log the height and position of the div it returns values but still gives me the error messages.

```
<div class="header">
<div id="nav-anchor"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid menu-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="images/logotype.png" alt="Logotype" title="" class="brand">
            </div><!-- end col md 6 brand -->
            <div class="col-md-6 menu">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#cases">Cases</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#meet">Meet us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Follow us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </div><!-- end col md 6 menu -->
        </div><!-- end row -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</div><!-- end header -->

$(document).ready(function(){

    /** 
     * This part does the "fixed navigation after scroll" functionality
     * We use the jQuery function scroll() to recalculate our variables as the 
     * page is scrolled/
     */
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // the "12" should equal the margin-top value for nav.stick
        var div_top = $('.header').offset().top;
    });

    /**
     * This part causes smooth scrolling using scrollto.js
     * We target all a tags inside the nav, and apply the scrollto.js to it.
     */
    $(".menu li a").click(function(evn){
        evn.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').scrollTo(this.hash, this.hash);
           if (window_top > div_top) {
                $('nav').addClass('stick');
            } else {
                $('nav').removeClass('stick');
            } 
    });

    /**
     * This part handles the highlighting functionality.
     * We use the scroll functionality again, some array creation and 
     * manipulation, class adding and class removing, and conditional testing
     */
    var aChildren = $("nav li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
    var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
    for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
        var aChild = aChildren[i];
        var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
        aArray.push(ahref);
    } // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
        var docHeight = $(document).height();

        for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
            var theID = aArray[i];
            var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
            var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
            if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("active");
            } else {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("active");
            }
        }

        if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
            if (!$("nav li:last-child a").hasClass("active")) {
                var navActiveCurrent = $(".active").attr("href");
                $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("active");
                $("nav li:last-child a").addClass("active");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `var window_top` is local variable inside window scroll event handler, and somewhy you use it inside `.menu li a` click event handler. It doesn't look good for me.

Answer (score 1):

window_top needs to be a global variable, also you can add the specified amount of pixels you need to the actual variable so `var div_top = $('.header').offset().top + 5;`

Comment: Making variable as global can solve the problem, but it's also not a bad idea to simply replace `window_top` with `$(window).scrollTop()`.